# Parallelize Crout using Openmp

Tags: c, openmp, linear-algebra

I am  new to openmp and I am trying to parallelize Crout method. But I am having trouble as the base code has lot of function call

```
static void croutBetaSolve(const int ROW, const int COL, const int DIM,
                           double * const LU) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int k = 0; k < ROW; ++k) {
    sum += LU[lindex(ROW,k,DIM)] * LU[lindex(k,COL,DIM)];
  }

  LU[lindex(ROW,COL,DIM)] -= sum;

  return;
}

static void croutAlphaSolve(const int ROW, const int COL, const int DIM,
                            double * const LU) {

  double sum = 0.0;
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int k = 0; k < COL; ++k) {
    sum += LU[lindex(ROW,k,DIM)] * LU[lindex(k,COL,DIM)];
  }

  LU[lindex(ROW,COL,DIM)] -= sum;
  LU[lindex(ROW,COL,DIM)] /= LU[lindex(COL,COL,DIM)];

  return;
}

void decompLU(const int DIM, double * const A, double * const LU) {
  int i, j;

  // If input and output array pointers are different initialise output
  // have to trust that A and LU don't overlap...
  if (LU != A) {
    memcpy(LU, A, DIM * DIM * sizeof(double));
  }

  // main LU iterations

  for (j = 0; j < DIM; ++j) {
    for (i = 0; i < j+1; ++i) {
      croutBetaSolve(i, j, DIM, LU);
    }
    for (i = j+1; i < DIM; ++i) {
      croutAlphaSolve(i, j, DIM, LU);
    }
  }

  return;
}
```

There are three function.

1. croutAlphaSolve - I have used simple omp parallel for. Should k be private or shared, also LU seems to be shared for this?
2. croutBetaSolve - Similar to the upper as there is only one loop. The main function changes after the loop.
3. decompLU - This is the main function which is called and I have no idea how to parallelize this. I have a feeling i and j loop will use one parallel for.

Can someone help??

Edit - For croutAlphaSolve and croutBetaSolve, the parallelism is taking time. For 1000 nodes, serial took 2sec but for parallel nothing printed in 1 min.

Also, for decompLU, i have used `#pragma omp parallel for` for three loops.
for (j = 0; j < DIM; ++j),for (i = 0; i < j+1; ++i) , for (i = j+1; i < DIM; ++i).

What can make it faster??

Comment: Don't use function calls in inner loop: you can use a third inner loop and avoid O(n^2) function calls. And above all, don't parallelize the inner loop!

Comment: As Jean-Claude indicated, parallel on inner loop is unproductive  even if you were to correct it with reduction clause. Among other things, it is likely to make it difficult to get omp simd reduction optimization.